# Program run correctly only in debug mode

Tags: c, debugging, microblaze

I wrote a simply Microblaze C application to test the board display with a button to toggle between hex and BCD mode.

Here is my code:

```
#include <xparameters.h>
#include <xgpio.h>

int main ()
{
    XGpio display, digit, bcd, butt; // four variables are defined named display, digit, bcd, butt
    int flag = 1;

    XGpio_Initialize (&display, XPAR_AXI_GPIO_0_DEVICE_ID);
    XGpio_SetDataDirection (&display,1,0); // set display as output ports
    XGpio_Initialize (&digit,XPAR_AXI_GPIO_1_DEVICE_ID);
    XGpio_SetDataDirection (&digit,1,0); // set digit as output ports
    XGpio_Initialize (&bcd,XPAR_AXI_GPIO_2_DEVICE_ID);
    XGpio_SetDataDirection (&bcd,1,0); // set bcd as output ports
    XGpio_Initialize (&butt, XPAR_AXI_GPIO_3_DEVICE_ID);
    XGpio_SetDataDirection (&butt,1,1); //set button as input port

    while(1)
    {
        if (XGpio_DiscreteRead (&butt, 1) == 1)
        {
            if (flag==1)
            { flag=0; }
            else
            { flag=1; }
        } // toggle flag

        XGpio_DiscreteWrite (&bcd, 1, flag); // set bcd to flag
        XGpio_DiscreteWrite (&digit, 1, 7); // set n°8 digit
        XGpio_DiscreteWrite (&display, 1, 99563243); // write to display
    }
}
```

When I debug on the board everything is OK. After downloading on FPGA the toggle doesn't work.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Try defining flag as Xuint32 rather than int.

Comment: I try with Xuint32 but the behavior is the same: debugging on board ok, downloading and running on FPGA toggle doesn't work, pressing button toggle ins't executed

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED
following code run fine. Defining flag as u32 and adding a delay cycle.

```
#include<xparameters.h>
#include<xgpio.h>

int main()
{
XGpio display, digit, bcd, sw;  // defined gpio variables
long int delay;                 // defined a delay variable
u32 flag=1;                     // defined a flag variable

XGpio_Initialize(&display, XPAR_AXI_GPIO_0_DEVICE_ID);
XGpio_SetDataDirection(&display,1,0);                   // set display as output ports
XGpio_Initialize(&digit,XPAR_AXI_GPIO_1_DEVICE_ID);
XGpio_SetDataDirection(&digit,1,0);                     // set digit as output ports
XGpio_Initialize(&bcd,XPAR_AXI_GPIO_2_DEVICE_ID);
XGpio_SetDataDirection(&bcd,1,0);                       // set bcd as output ports
XGpio_Initialize(&sw, XPAR_AXI_GPIO_3_DEVICE_ID);
XGpio_SetDataDirection(&sw,1,1);                        //set sw as input port

while(1)
{
    flag= XGpio_DiscreteRead(&sw, 1);
    XGpio_DiscreteWrite(&bcd, 1, flag);         // set bcd to flag
    XGpio_DiscreteWrite(&digit, 1, 7);          // set n°8 digit
    XGpio_DiscreteWrite(&display, 1, 5888999);  // write to display
    for(delay=0;delay<3000000;delay++){};       // delay cycle
}
}
```